# Sencha Touch: update view during function

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, view, sencha-touch

Here is what should happen:
I have a button with a label and an icon.
When I tap the button some actions will take place which will take some time. Therefore I want to replace the icon of the button with some loading-icon during the processing.

Normal Icon: [image: Normal Icon]

Icon replaced by loading gif: [image: Icon replaced by loading gif]

So in pseudo code it would be:

```
fancyFunction(){
   replaceIconWithLoadingIcon();
   doFancyStuff();
   restoreOldIcon();
}
```

However the screen isn't updated during the execution of the function. Here ist my code:

```
onTapButton: function(view, index, target, record, event){
    var indexArray = new Array();
    var temp = record.data.photo_url;
    record.data.photo_url = "img/loading_icon.gif";
    alert('test1');
    /*
     * Do magic stuff
     */
}
```

The icon will be replaced using the above code, but not until the function has terminated. Meaning, when the `alert('1')` appears, the icon is not yet replaced.

I already tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188754/sencha-touch-panel-hide-show-works-only-after-resize) without success.
I also tried `view.hide()` followed by `view.show()` but these commands weren't executed until the function terminated, too.

Let me know if you need further information. Any suggestions would be far more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution displaying the mask during my actions are performed. The key to my solution was on [this website.](http://appointsolutions.com/2011/08/sencha-touch-loadmask-delayed-rendering/#comment-14109)

In my controller I did the following:

```
showLoadingScreen: function(){
    Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
        xtype: 'loadmask',
        message: 'Loading...'
    });
},

onTapButton: function(view, index, target, record, event){
    //Show loading mask
    setTimeout(function(){this.showLoadingScreen();}.bind(this),1);
    // Do some magic
    setTimeout(function(){this.doFancyStuff(para,meter);}.bind(this),400);
    // Remove loading screen
    setTimeout(function(){Ext.Viewport.unmask();}.bind(this),400);
},
```

The replacing of the icons worked quite similar:

```
onTapButton: function(view, index, target, record, event){
    //Replace the icon
    record.data.photo_url = 'img/loading_icon.gif';
    view.refresh();
    // Do some magic
    setTimeout(function(){this.doFancyStuff(para,meter);}.bind(this),400);
},

doFancyStuff: function(para, meter){
    /*
     * fancy stuff
     */
    var index = store.find('id',i+1);
    var element = store.getAt(index);
    element.set('photo_url',img);
}
```

Thank you for your help Barrett and sha!

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem here is that your execution task is executing in the main UI thread. In order to let UI thread do animation you need to push your `doFancyStuff()` function into something like http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.DelayedTask

Keep in mind though, that you would need to revert it your icon only after fancy stuff is complete.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Even if your suggestion sounds perfect I run into an error saying: `cannot call method 'apply' of undefined` as it is stated in the following bug report: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?260115-Error-with-DelayedTask-Sencha-Touch-2.2-RC

Comment: What version of ST are you using?

Comment: We are currently using 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

To update any button attributes you shoudl try to access the button itself. Either with a ComponentQuery or through the controllers getter. For Example:

var button = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[name=YOURBUTTONNAME]')[0];
button.setIcon('img/loading_icon.gif');

that shold update your button's icon.

also when you get a ref to the button you will have access to all the methods availble to an Ext.Button object:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Button-method-setIcon

Comment: Hi Barrett. Thank you for your quick answer, too. Your suggestion works ... almost. When I display the result in a webbrowser the behavior is as expected. But as soon as I run it as an app on Android - what is the real purpose - the icon is updated AFTER the function has executed as pointed out in the starting post.